# How to send Adaptive card from API

Tags: api, botframework, adaptive-cards

We are working on Conversations BOT, for a particular use-case we need to send Adaptive card via API, please help, if there are anyways.

Comment: Hey, can we get a few more details on your situation? Are you using the bot framework? Which language, where do you want to send the card to? Maybe reading this could help aswell :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TimCadenbach, Yes we are using BOT framework, and the language used is .NET, this card we need to send over the outlook.

Comment: To further clarify; you have a user that is conversing with a bot. Then, at some point (some intent/trigger/dialog), you need an adaptive card sent to the user's Outlook via email? Please flush out the scenario further for us.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried storing card in json?
String can be send over API calls.